# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named. Problem with finding module

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I'm struggling with using one of the python scripts I've written. I know there have been a couple similar questions to this one already, however I have tried pretty much everything I could find, and nothing works...

When I try to run a test program I get met with

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'v6-average-py'
```

I'll explain better throughout this post.

My file structure is this:

```
mean_package
|-README.md
|-setup.py
|-algorithm_pkg
       |-__init__.py
```

**Setup.py**:

```
from os import path
from codecs import open
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='v6-average-py',
    version="1.0.0",
    description='v6 average',
    long_description="description",
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/IKNL/v6-average-py',
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=[
        'vantage6-client',
    ]
)
```

****init**.py** is just two defined methods.

Then I run

```
pip install -e .
```

Which gives a bunch of requirement statisfied and

```
Running setup.py develop for v6-average-py
Successfully installed v6-average-py-1.0.0
```

And finally when it try to run a program I called **testscript.py** it fails at the first part with

```
client = ClientMockProtocol(
    datasets=[".\\MOCK_DATA.csv", ".\\MOCK_DATA1.csv"],
    module="v6-average-py"
)
```

It fails at

```
module="v6-average-py"
```

because the module can't be found I assume.
From what I have seen from similar questions it's either a problem with using different python versions, which I don't think is the issue here (running everything using pyenv, python 3.7.9 so it's all being run/installed with that).
I have also tried solutions where the problem has been `find_packages()` or the ****init**.py** file with no luck.
Maybe it's being put somewhere it can't be found?
Any input would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried pip show package_name to check whether it is actually present in your environment?

Comment: I just checked to make sure and it shows well with all the information I specified in the setup.py file

Comment: Well if it's dynamic importing, it shouldn't have hyphens, instead, these should be underscores. I guess the package would be installed with underscores only.

Comment: Do you mean in testscript.py? So instead of calling ````"v6-average-py"```` I would be calling ````__v6-average-py__````? Tried that but still giving error

Comment: When you used pip show it would be the `v6_average_py` package right? Try this in the module, I think `v6-average-py` wouldn't be the package name here,

Comment: Ah my bad I misunderstood. No unfortunately when I run pip show it outputs ````Name: v6-average-py````. Thus ````v6_average_py```` did not work:/ Truly at a loss about what's not working

Comment: Would maybe the location have anything to do with it? Or is that somewhat irrelevant?

Comment: Oh, that's strange, importing a module with hyphens, I haven't seen that kind of behavior before. Let me check the Github link mentioned and see if I can help

Comment: Thank you! The Github link is a project that I am trying to use, so it is not something I have developed! I am using one of their examples that can be found here https://docs.vantage6.ai/algorithm-development/create-new-algorithm

Comment: What is odd is after the ````pip install -e .```` in the folder, the created information folder is called ````v6_average_py.egg-info```` while all the info inside is with hyphens